# iPhone backplate mod: On what side of the iPhone 4S backplate should I paint?

Tags: iphone, customization

My iPhone backplate was broken. So, to make something good out of this, I want to create an effect like this:

[image]

I would like to fill the cracks with paint, but I have other options too.

Will painting it on the inside affect any electronics?

Also, is the Apple logo made up of metal or paint?

Comment: Pay attention to the places where the case has metal contacts that rub against pins or other metal items that stick out of the phone. (equally important is the place where a non-conductive shield may be placed to avoid shorting the logic board if metal is exposed) Just be sure the paint you get is thinned in a way that it will dry in the small - capillary cracks. An epoxy resin might be a good thing to research if you hope to have adhesive and color in one package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try painting the glass with paint, not just the bursts, but the whole plate on the outside.
Let the paint dry and then scratch the surface clean with a hard plastic object (so you don't scratch the glass).
Normally the paint will have dried in the bursts and you shouldn't be able to scratch off the paint (while the paint on the glass will be scratched off).

About the electronics; if you use normal paint, it won't harm the electronics.

But why don't buy a [new cover on eBay](http://www.ebay.com/itm/Rear-Back-Battery-Housing-Faceplate-Case-Cover-White-For-Apple-iPhone-4Gs-4s-/280923170219?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item41685365ab) for just $9? You can simply fix this yourself within 2 minutes!

Comment: You can separate the white paint from the glass. Just have to use thinner. If I remove the white, will I be able to paint other colours?

Comment: Even if that's the case, I don't think you can paint such a detailed picture on glass... The more I think about it, the more I'm sure. They cracked the glass and filled it with paint.

Comment: I think you read my question wrong. I have a *cracked* phone. And I want to fill it with paint. I just don’t know how to go about it.

Comment: Oh, I totally misread the question. My apologies. Try painting the glass with paint, not just the bursts, but the whole plate on the outside. Let the paint dry and then scratch the surface clean with a hard plastic object (so you don't scratch the glass). Normally the paint will have dried in the bursts and you shouldn't be able to scratch the paint off (while the paint on the glass will be scratched off)

Comment: Ok I will try this after someone else also weighs in with their method.

Comment: @duci9y to be fair you only edited that information in afterwards :)

Comment: I was making the edit while Michiel was answering, so yeah, he could’ve answered first. Sorry about that.

Comment: No problem! Please see my updated answer (especially the last part!)

Comment: Thanks! I just wanted to be more creative with my phone, that's why I am not fixing it.